# Using ViewGroup.addView() to add a GestureOverlayView to a SurfaceView game panel

Tags: android, surfaceview

After much help from the good people here, I finally almost got my little game panel (thats a surfaceview class) up and running with a GestureOverlayView.  Through the use of addView I finally was able to add the GestureOverlayView and get it to work, the trouble is that calling this:

```
    /** create the login form */
private ViewGroup _createGameStuffs() {
  GestureOverlayView gestures = new GestureOverlayView(this);       
  gestures.setOrientation(gestures.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
  gestures.setEventsInterceptionEnabled(true);
  gestures.setGestureStrokeType(gestures.GESTURE_STROKE_TYPE_MULTIPLE);

  gestures.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

  //GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
  gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
  Panel p = new Panel(this); //my game view
  panel.addView(p,0);       //add it to the group
  panel.addView(gestures,1); //add the gestureoverlayview i made to the group

  return panel;
}

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
               mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.myspells);

                 // create the panel to enclose everything
               View mainPanel = _createGameStuffs();

              // show the panel on the screen
              setContentView(mainPanel);
              //setContentView(p);
 }
```

Depending upon which index I give which view takes presedence.  This leads me to believe my game panel has to be added as a child view to the GestureOverlayView, is this correct? If so, how do I get at the children views of the GestureOverlayView?  Or is it the other way around, GestureOverlayView becomes a child of my main view?